# Unable to modify dataset attribute if it is a nested array

Tags: python, h5py

In [this HDF5](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64iy-fZJMoSOFBTZ3p4dnlzd0U/view?usp=sharing), I need to update the first row of attribute

```
h5['Model/dataset'].attrs['num_cells']
```

So, I do the following:

```
import h5py

h5 = h5py.File('MCPL507_HS_3_2_orig.newrom','a')
numcells = h5['Model/dataset'].attrs['num_cells'][:]

#Print before re-assigment
print numcells[0]
print type(numcells[0])

numcells[0] = [230,230,30]

#Print after re-assigment
print numcells[0]
print type(numcells[0])

h5['Model/dataset'].attrs.modify('num_cells',numcells)
```

Which throws me an exception:

```
File "C:\Users\nnolde\PycharmProjects\HDF5_Stuff\MinExample.py", line 16, in <module>
    h5['Model/dataset'].attrs.modify('num_cells',numcells)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\attrs.py", line 221, in modify
    raise TypeError("Shape of data is incompatible with existing attribute")
TypeError: Shape of data is incompatible with existing attribute
```

It seems like the attribute uses some sort of scale/dimension, since you can´t modify the shape of the data?! I´m not even changing the array shape, only a few elements. I thought an attribute was arbitrary and as long as you don´t attempt to change the data type (or array shape), you could modify to your needs. Or is this some Python/C port bug?

Note: I can´t use `__setitem__`, this will cause our custom application to not recognize the HDF5 anymore.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem and maybe even how to solve it?

Comment: h5py has problems with nested arrays as attributes and converts them to higher dimensional arrays. The C version of the library probably can do it correctly. I tested it in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inspecting your HDF5 file:

[image]

you see that num_cells is a nested array (size 3) of an array (size 3).

However, after reading in Python.

```
h5 = h5py.File('MCPL507_HS_3_2_orig.newrom','a')
numcells = h5['Model/dataset'].attrs['num_cells']
print(numcells.shape)
```

the shape of numcells is `(3,3)` which means that h5py changes the nested linear arrays into a two-dimensional array when reading the attribute.

Even without modifying, just writing it back using `modify(name, value)` you get the "Shape of data is incompatible with existing attribute" error.

You could read the attribute, modify it and assign it back like this:

```
numcells = h5['Model/dataset'].attrs['num_cells']
numcells[0] = [230,230,30]
h5['Model/dataset'].attrs['num_cells'] = numcells
```

but this changes the shape of the attribute in the HDF5 file to 3x3 (and anyway you said you cannot use it):

[image]

So I tried to trick h5py and split the attribute into three one-dimensional arrays to create manually what was there, then set it again:

```
numcells = h5['Model/dataset'].attrs['num_cells']
numcells[0] = [230,230,30]
dummy = [numcells[0], numcells[1], numcells[2]]
h5['Model/dataset'].attrs['num_cells'] = dummy
```

But h5py knows better and converts them to a 3x3 array again!

Summary:

h5py converts nested arrays into higher dimensional numpy array upon reading and writing of attributes and does not allow modifying of attributes without changing the shape if they are nested arrays. This could be seen as a bug. The best you can do is avoiding nested arrays in favor of higher dimensional arrays as attribute shapes because they can be modified without throwing an error.

Comment: Thx so much Trilarion, for looking into this! By now I figured it´s gotta be some sort of bug. I´ll post this on the official h5py forum and see what they come back with and if they are willing to fix it. I´ll keep this thread updated with their answer.